# How to convert the following string to json object?

Tags: javascript

```
var str = '""{""as"":""N9K-93180YC-EX""}""';
```

I tried with the regular expression

```
var str1 =  str.replace(/\"/g, "");
```

After that, I got the string like `"{as:N9K-93180YC-EX}"`. So I can't parse the string with `JSON.parse(str1)`. It's throwing an error like,

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token an in JSON at position 1.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like an X/Y problem. Better to fix the broken API that's serving you that string, and have it serve proper JSON instead.

Comment: `JSON.parse("{'as':'N9K-93180YC-EX'}")` , Write a regex to get the same formate

Comment: @deepeshkumar, no, that does not work with single quotes in a [JSON](https://json.org)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beside the API problem, you could replace double double quotes with a single double quote and omit the first and last double quote for parsing.

```js
var str = '""{""as"":""N9K-93180YC-EX""}""',
    object = JSON.parse(str.replace(/\"\"/g, '"').slice(1, -1));

console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be an alternative approach

```
var str = '""{""as"":""N9K-93180YC-EX""}""';
var str1 = str.replace(/\"/g, "'");
str1 = str1.replace(/''/g, "'");   
var result = str1.slice(1,-1);
alert(JSON.parse('"'+result+'"'));
```